# If I use a trainer card that removes damage, can I remove less than that amount of damage?

Tags: pokemon

If a trainer card states that it removes 60 points of damage, can you use it to remove 50 points or less of damage?  I have one card that says up to 30 points of damage, so I know I can use it to remove 10, 20, or 30, but this card states 60 and does not use the words "up to".

Comment: Please don't group questions together in the same question unless they're integrally related and don't make much sense being asked separately. I've removed the second of your questions, please click the **Ask Question** button and ask it separately. You can still access the text of that question by visiting the [revision history](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/posts/22782/revisions) of this post, which you can usually get to by clicking the "edited X time ago" link in the bottom center of your post.

Answer (score 3):

In Pokémon, there are some core rules. Two of them are relevant here:

1. *"Do as much as you can"* -> you can heal less than given amount of damage
2. *"Every card played must have some effect"* -> you can't heal zero damage